# How to check if an element exists within the body with cypress?

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, cypress, e2e-testing, end-to-end

I want to check whether the nextjs-portal tag appears in the body of my page and if so, then click on it.

How can I do that with cypress?

This works, but I need the if block now:

```
cy.get('nextjs-portal').click();
```

Something like

```
if (cy.get('nextjs-portal')) {
  cy.get('nextjs-portal').click();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any if here. If the element does not exist, `cy.get('nextjs-portal')` will time out and no click will happen.

If you really really need conditional testing, it can be done, but it's usually an anti-pattern:

```js
cy
  .get('body')
  .then($body => {
    if ($body.find('.nextjs-portal').length) {
      // now you know the element was found in the DOM
    } else {
      // your element was not found in the DOM
    }
  });
```

Comment: But what if the element doesn't exist? It is a popup that occurs on errors and is not always present..

Comment: I think you should remove the need for conditional testing (https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing#Definition) and then write a test where you click on this element.

Comment: @Codehan25: ok, I updated my answer, but I still think there's usually no need for such a condition.

Comment: Works for now :), thanks! - but I'll check the documentation as well :)